# Entity reference Autocomplete widget performance issue on add/remove

Tags: 7, entities

I have created content type and using entity reference module.I am facing very slow performance on entity reference Autocomplete widget while add more or remove option in admin side. Its taking time to responding. Any one have had this issue.

Comment: How many nodes do you have?

Comment: approximately more than 10k.